# Selecting from different tables based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

I Have a table `comments` ->

```
id | comment | type | userid | 
1    Hello     human    9
2    Hi        robot    4
3    Gnaw!     animal   1
4    Boo       ghost    2
```

Also i have four more tables `human`,`robot`,`ghost` and `animal`
These tables contains some basic details about themselves...

Now I have a know value of comment say : $id = 3
if i do

```
 $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  type FROM comments WHERE id = $id");
 while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
        $table = $row['type'];          
        $table_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $table"));
 }
```

this will fetch me all the data about the one who commented but this will prove to be too slow....is there any way i can combine this in **one single query ?**

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with left joins.

```
SELECT c.type, COALESCE(h.detail,r.detail,a.detail,g.detail)
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN human h ON c.type = 'human' AND c.id = h.id
LEFT JOIN robot r ON c.type = 'robot' AND c.id = r.id
LEFT JOIN animal a ON c.type = 'animal' AND c.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN ghost g ON c.type = 'ghost' AND c.id = g.id
```

Another way would be to do a UNION on the four tables and then join those:

```
SELECT c.type, q1.detail
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 'human' AS type, detail FROM human
  UNION
  SELECT 'robot', detail FROM robot
  (etc.)
) q1 ON c.type = q1.type AND q1.id = c.id
```

I would prefer the second option, because this one makes it easier to join lots of detail-columns. I don't think there's much of a difference perfomance-wise.

Comment: COALESCE return the first not empty value, by doing left JOIN you "fetch" all but you only display the not empty, clever solution :)

Comment: which would be better ?

Comment: @popovitsj The second solution isn't possible with **MySQL**, MySQL has no support for CTE's

Comment: @RoshanShaw can you link to a fiddle that shows it's not working?

Comment: We'll have to live with it ;-). However with or without CTE's it's still an ugly solution caused by the EAV antimodel

Comment: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' error @popovitsj

Comment: O.. that has to do with the used strings. You'll probably have to do something like `CAST('human' AS VARCHAR(20))`. where VARCHAR(20) has to be the datatype of column comments.type. But the first solution should work without this.

Comment: still not working can u give a sqlfiddle ? @popovitsj

Comment: Sorry, but writing an sqlfiddle with demo data is a lot of work. If you create a fiddle that shows it not working I will take a look at it.